# Get a random even number in an interval?

Tags: java

Could someone please explain how this works.

```
int min = 2;
int max = 10;
int random = (int)(Math.random()*(max-min+1))/2*2+2; 
System.out.println("The number is " + random);
```

Not sure about the formula part - (max-min+1))/2*2+2
Thank you!

Comment: It shouldn't be `+2`, but rather `+min`.

Comment: Also, it should be `max-min+2`, otherwise you will get the max value less frequently than the others.

Comment: `Math.random()` gives a random between `0` and `1`, Multiplying it by `max-min+1` will put it between `0` and `max-min+1`. `x/2*2` looks useless, and `+ min` will put it between `min` and `max+1`. But as it is an `int` and `1` never returned, it will give the wanted interval.

Comment: I cannot understand your question

Comment: This is a poor way of creating uniform random integer values.  You should use `nextInt` method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can think of this mathematically.

The formula is just a like a mathematical function:

```
f(x) = floor(floor(x * (10 - 2 + 1)) / 2) * 2 + 2
```

The `int` cast is basically flooring the number and the integer division by 2 is just a floor as well.

Given that the domain of the function = {0 ≤ x < 1} (We know this because that's what `Math.random()` does), we can look at each step and see how the range of the function changes.

```
x * (10 - 2 + 1)
```

This makes the range = {0 ≤ y < 9}

```
floor(x * (10 - 2 + 1)) // adding floor function
```

This makes the range = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

```
floor(floor(x * (10 - 2 + 1)) / 2) // dividing by two and flooring
```

This makes the range = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

```
floor(floor(x * (10 - 2 + 1)) / 2) * 2 // multiplying by 2
```

This makes the range = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}

```
floor(floor(x * (10 - 2 + 1)) / 2) * 2 + 2 // adding 2
```

This makes the range = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}

As you can see, the only possible outputs are 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 in the end.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for...Thanks!

Comment: Btw `Math.random()` function domain is 0 ***≤*** x < 1

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an already implemented method of [`ThreadLocalRandom#nextInt(int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,%20int)) which can be used like below:

```
int min = 2;
int max = 10;

// get local random
ThreadLocalRandom rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

int randomEven = (rnd.nextInt(min, max) / 2) * 2
```